# How can I gracefully degrade CSS viewport units?

Tags: css, cross-browser, responsive-design, graceful-degradation

CSS viewport units (`vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`) are great, and I want to start using them for fonts -- but I noticed [here](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) that they aren't that widely supported.  I tried to google any best practices for graceful degradation in unsupported browsers, but couldn't find anything useful.  Are there any better ways beyond doing something like:

```
    h1 {
      font-size: 120%;    /* for unsupported browsers */
      font-size: 5.3vmin; /* for supported browsers */
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Native usage

You'll at least want to provide a fallback:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 36px; /* Some tweener fallback that doesn't look awful */ 
  font-size: 5.4vw;  
}
```

Also tells about mimicing the functionality with FitText.js.

For more information, read Chris Coyier's "Viewport Sized Typography" http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: The post has code in it, external resource is a wider explanation, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot gracefully degrade the viewport units *in CSS* simply because there is nothing conceptually even remotely similar in older versions of CSS.

For example, setting font size to `120%` does not address the issue at all: it simply sets the font size 1.2 times the parent element’s font size, quite independently of viewport dimensions.

It is, however, possible to approximate the effects of viewport units using client-side JavaScript so that you get the viewport properties and then set the `font-size` property based on them. See e.g. answers to the question [Is there any cross-browser javascript for making vh and vw units work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948713/is-there-any-cross-browser-javascript-for-making-vh-and-vw-units-work).

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to properly use css-values viewport-relative-lengths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175730/how-to-properly-use-css-values-viewport-relative-lengths/30180320#30180320), I don't think it's correct to use viewport units outside of restricting them with `@media` queries for minimum height and width of the viewport, and even then, I think it should only be used when you know that the page they'll be applying to is very small (e.g. a business-card style page), and would otherwise leave the whole viewport screen empty handed.

---

In other words, what exactly are you looking for when you say `font-size: 5.3vmin`?

What if I cascade multiple windows one by one, only leaving enough room in each viewport as to see three lines of normal text?  The text at `5.3vmin` will be so small at to be unintelligible!

Likewise, if I have a huge monitor (say, [Seiki 39" @ 3840x2160](http://amzn.com/B00DOPGO2G), which, I must point out, is quite affordable at below 400 USD), and you use `font-size: 5.3vmin` for all your headers on a page with a lengthy article, then you're stripping my ability and comfort to fully enjoy all the extra lines of text that my monitor can support, instead having 5 headers occupy more than a quarter of the screen, which instead could have been filled by a hundred of extra lines of text.

Comment: good commentary on best practices for usage of viewport-relative-lengths