# Parent height auto with children divs of full width and variable height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a relatively browser-compatible way of allowing the height of a parent div to expand with its children of `width: 100%` and some percentage height. I need the parent to have `height: 100%` because the first child's height is dependent on it. I want a background image on the parent div that's aligned to the bottom of the entire page which overflows the screen, but the parent div's height is limited to the height of the screen because its height is set to 100%.

In my case, I've set the following properties:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%:
    position: relative;
}

.child1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 520px;
    max-height: 960px;
    position: relative;
}

.child2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I can position a div inside of the second child to be absolutely positioned relative to the bottom of the second child, but I need to have `overflow: hidden` set on the second child for other elements, and since the background size is supposed to scale with the width of the page, it gets clipped on large screens.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qxbu0mom/

edit:

Thanks to Terry for pointing out I can use vh; I can just change the first child's height to 100vh and remove `height: 100%` from the parent.

Comment: "parent to have height: 100%" but you didn't tell us that 100% is relative to *what*? Also, including an image would be very helpful in explaining what you want to achieve precisely.

Comment: @Terry added a JSFiddle! All elements up to the parent have `height: 100%` set, so relative to the screen

Comment: You can use viewport units, i.e.g `100vh` for the height.

Comment: @Terry ok, but what about for < IE9?

Comment: You'll have to use alternative methods then, such as JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948713/is-there-any-cross-browser-javascript-for-making-vh-and-vw-units-work

Comment: you can do this with jQuery ...

Comment: I'm aware; I was looking for a solution that didn't require JavaSciprt