# CSS: How to use vmin unit in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code

```
.image.medium {
    width:10vmin;
    height:10vmin;
}

.image.small {
    width:6vmin;
    height:6vmin;
}

.image.medium.as_big {
    margin:5vmin;
}

.image.small.as_big {
    margin:7vmin;
}
```

AS you can se it contains those "vmin" units, which are not of use on IE9 because it uses "vm".

I don't have IE in my computer like to check, it's a linux computer anyway, so I don't know how I could make this css usable by both, IE9 and the other browsers.

Also I was thinking, should I use the javascript workaround instead? I just want vmin, according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units it's not supported by so many browsers, and I would like to be able to zoom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, standard declarations should be placed after the non-standard/experimental features.

For instance, in this particular case it should be:

```css
.image.medium {
    width: 10vm;   /* fallback for IE9 */
    width: 10vmin;

    height: 10vm;  /* fallback for IE9 */
    height: 10vmin;
}
```

The latter declaration is interpreted by modern web browsers supporting `vmin`. And the former declaration acts as a fallback to the latter one.

---

### Cross Browser Solutions

There are also polyfills for viewport relative lengths, for instance:

- [vminpoly](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly) by Sebastian Ferreyra — A polyfill for CSS units `vw`, `vh` & `vmin`.
- [Prefixfree - Viewport Relative Units Plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/#plugins) by Lea Verou — A [polyfill](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/plugins/prefixfree.viewport-units.js) for `vw`, `vh`, and `vmin`.
- [Viewport Units Buggyfill](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill) by Rodney Rehm — A polyfill for viewport `vh`, `vw` `vmin`, `vmax` for Mobile Safari.
- [Is there any cross-browser javascript for making vh and vw units work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948713/is-there-any-cross-browser-javascript-for-making-vh-and-vw-units-work)

Comment: I don't have enough points for vote up! so this would comment is my vote up!

Comment: I just got +2 now I can!