# how to detect full height of window using only css for mobile website

Tags: css

I want to detect window height for mobile website using only css as "vh" does not seem to work on mobile.

Is there any way to use "vh" or an equivalent on mobile websites?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948713/is-there-any-cross-browser-javascript-for-making-vh-and-vw-units-work

Comment: but i dont want to use jquery. 
And vh or vw is not working in android mobile