# CSS - Make page content fill all the screen height

Tags: html, css

I am new with CSS and need some help, please. Although it seems to be simple to solve, I am already working in this problem for about 4 hours. I found many similar questions on internet, but each case is particulary different from mine, and the "solutions" can't solve my problem (already tried most of them).

Here is the basic structure of my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="head">
            <div id="head_content">
                HEARDER
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="body">

            <div id="menu">
                MENU
            </div>

            <div id="page">
                PAGE CONTENT
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="foot">
            <div id="foot_content">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS I am trying to implement:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #DEDEDE;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #115293;
    background-color: #1976D2;
}

#head #head_content {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#body {
    width: 1000px;
//    height: 100%;
//    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
//    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    border-right: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}

#body #menu {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
//    height: 100%;
//    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #94C9FF;
}

#body #page {
    overflow: hidden;
//    height: 100%;
//    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    border-left: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#foot {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #115293;
    background-color: #1976D2;
}

#foot #foot_content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Obs: Commented lines are SOME of the solutions I already tried.

Here is what I got so far:

[image]

And finally here is what I really need:

[image]

Comment: u are just missing height property for #main. add that in and add height back in body, #page #menu with value set to 100%. https://jsfiddle.net/9pao4qs1/

Comment: @JungJoo, doing this way the page goes before the foot div... I'd like the foot div be in the last bottom of the page. Do you know how to fix? Thank you!

Comment: @JungJoo, I used in the wrapper (#body div) this parameter height: calc(100% - Npx) and could solve the problem. But now I have another problem, when the content is bigger then the screen, it does not increase height automatically... https://jsfiddle.net/9pao4qs1/2/

Comment: oh i missed that. I just added clear: left to footer and changed it to float. https://jsfiddle.net/f11w1ryp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you were having trouble getting the `#body` div to be the full height of the remaining space is because each of the wrapping elements needed `height:100%` not just one of them. That means `#main`, `#body`, `#page` and `#menu`.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #DEDEDE;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
  height:100%;
}

#head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #115293;
    background-color: #1976D2;
}

#head #head_content {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#body {
  height:100%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    border-right: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}

#body #menu {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #94C9FF;
  height:100%;
}

#body #page {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    border-left: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height:100%;
}

#foot {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #115293;
    background-color: #1976D2;
}

#foot #foot_content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="head">
            <div id="head_content">
                HEARDER
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="body">

            <div id="menu">
                MENU
            </div>

            <div id="page">
                PAGE CONTENT
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="foot">
            <div id="foot_content">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dylan! Strange, I added a comment here "yesterday" (4 am), but it disappeared... Well, I already tried the 100% height as you did, but the problem is that I need the foot div in the last bottom of the page, and when we add this 100% height, there is a part of the page before the foot div. Do you know how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: I used in the wrapper (#body div) this parameter height: calc(100% - Npx) and could solve the "over height" problem. But now I have another problem, when the content is bigger then the screen, it does not increase height automatically... https://jsfiddle.net/9pao4qs1/2/  ... Please, do you know how to solve? Thanks!

Comment: Well, another step donne but still have problems... Now the code works with dynamic content (flexible height), the footer always stays in the end of page (screen). But the content vertical borders do not follow the height... Please, have a look https://jsfiddle.net/r56oqg41/

Comment: Hi @Guybrush, might be able to help but please post as a new question to stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about this... Thanks!

Comment: Dylan, here it is. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193035/css-dynamic-content-height-without-vertical-border

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way--

Just use the height unit as `vh(viewport height)` relative to viewport. Add rest of your css to get desired width effect.

**checkout the snippet**

```css
#main {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 10vh;
  }
#body {
  background-color:grey;
  height:80vh;
  }
#foot {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 10vh;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="head">
            <div id="head_content">
                HEARDER
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="body">

            <div id="menu">
                MENU
            </div>

            <div id="page">
                PAGE CONTENT
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="foot">
            <div id="foot_content">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can find compatibility here---

[vh compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

**EDIT**

As fallback for vh unit I think you can use javascript . Through javascript you can get the window size. Then specify the height of the footer as percentage of the window height.

[This question can be good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948713/is-there-any-cross-browser-javascript-for-making-vh-and-vw-units-work)

Comment: Hi neophyte! Hummm... never heard about this solution before. Do you know about compatibility? Tomorrow I will make a reasearch and tests, and let you know. Here is 4am now. Thank you!

Comment: added browser compatibility in the answer.

Comment: Well, it's a relative new CSS parameter, the compatibility is limited, I will prefer other approach for now... maybe in a year or two this approach would be the best way to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: after your comment I tried for some fallback approach. Added it in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I prefer not to use javascript, only CSS... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to css based on the size of content you require the content to be, just change the pixels based on the content you want:-

```
div#page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Hi! I do not want to have a fixed height... the foot div must be in the last bottom of the screen... Thanks!